# Is there any way to change focus of browser tabs in robot?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, browser-automation

I am using robot framework+python+selenium to create an automation framework. 
I am stuck at this point.

On this website. When the link 'a' is clicked, a new tab is opened. On this new new I want to test functionality. My problem is I'm not sure how to change the focus from one tab to another. I tried the switch browser keyword as well as the select window keyword. No luck.

Comment: `On this website` which site? where is your code trials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the following code change focus of the windows using [selenium2Library](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html).

```
@{windows_num} =  List Windows
${nWindows} =  Get Length  ${windows_num}
${latest_window} =  Evaluate  ${nWindows}-1
Select Window  @{windows_num}[${latest_window}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution here, that worked for me: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tVgC-oQVKs

Comment: This video does make use of the same keyword as motioned in my answer for change of focus. Good to know that you have resolved your issue.